# Previous versions of the dataset from the Yelp Dataset Challenge

Tags: data-request

Yelp periodically released data they have collected and encourage people to compete in a data analysis competition. The data for the current competition can be downloaded  [here](https://www.yelp.com/dataset).

In the [FAQ](https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/faq) they state that they do not distribute versions of the dataset from older competitions. I was curious if anyone knew of anywhere on the web where I can find older versions of the dataset?

Comment: bump. I would also like to know this! (for closure prediction.....)

Comment: please clarify which dataset challenge you are looking for (photo, sentiment, graph) https://www.yelp.com/dataset/challenge

Answer (score 1):

I found one source of old Yelp dataset challenge data, from the Academic Torrents site. Since Yelp explicitly doesn't share old data, use at your own peril.

[dataset summary](https://academictorrents.com/details/19c3aa2166d7bfceaf3d76c0d36f812e0f1b87bc)

[magnet link](http://magnet:?xt=urn:btih:19c3aa2166d7bfceaf3d76c0d36f812e0f1b87bc&tr=http%3A%2F%2Facademictorrents.com%2Fannounce.php&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969)

- test_photo_to_biz.csv.tgz 5.02MB
- test_photos.tgz   7.10GB
- train.csv.tgz 7.29kB
- train_photo_to_biz_ids.csv.tgz    1.17MB
- train_photos.tgz  7.03GB

I am not sure what year this corresponds to, but it was added as a torrent at 2016-05-12 02:26:53, so it's definitely not from this year.

Comment: seems to be same data as Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/yelp-restaurant-photo-classification